# Oracle 12c Datapatch Error

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

We have an old Oracle 12c database server that is not up to date (version 12.1.0.1.0). Unforunately a full version upgrade is out of scope right now, but I was hoping to at least apply the latest patch bundle we have on hand, which would take us to 12.1.0.1.160719 and fix a few vulnerabilities.

I used OPatch and got everything applied without incident, but when I tried to run the datapatch utility afterward I recieved the following errors:

```
SQL Patching tool version 12.1.0.1.0 on Thu Oct 17 12:10:58 2019
Copyright (c) 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to database...OK
Determining current state...
Currently installed SQL Patches:
Currently installed C Patches: 23530410
Adding patches to installation queue and performing prereq checks...
Installation queue:
  Nothing to roll back
  The following patches will be applied: 23530410
catconInit: database is not open
Installing patches...
Patch installation complete.  Total patches installed: 1
Validating logfiles...
Patch 23530410 apply:
  logfile:  (no errors)

See support note 1609718.1 for information on how to resolve the above errors

SQL Patching tool complete on Thu Oct 17 12:11:41 2019
catconExec: catconInit has not been runcatconWrapUp: catconInit has not been run
```

I've found similar errors on Google about 'catconInit: database is not open on the default instance' but nothing that is exactly the same message as mine. In fact, when I Google the last error message 'catconExec: catconInit has not been runcatconWrapUp: catconInit has not been run' I only get one result--the Oracle Support page for this error (Doc ID 1609718.1). Unfortunately, we do not have an ongoing support contract and I cannot see the cause/solution for this.

Also:

- There is only one database/instance on this server, and I specify
  that with the datapatch parameter
- The database is open per V$INSTANCE, and both myself and the application can query it just fine
- I've been a DBA for a few years now, but I'm new to Oracle specifically

---

Does anyone have any ideas? Can anyone relay the information from the support doc? Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT

- OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Rerun of 'datapatch -verbose -db MyDatabase' produces the exact same output (just with newer timestamps)
- The associated log file from the most recent run of datapatch (D:\oracle\MyDatabase\cfgtoollogs\opatch\opatch2019-11-05_13-29-08PM_1):

[image: patch log]

Comment: Try to run datapatch -verbose again and post complete output along with log file(log file generated in $ORACLE_HOME/cfgtlogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_xxx/sqlpatch_invocation,log) .What O/s and edition?/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I reran datapatch -verbose -db MyDatabase and got the exact same output just with newer timestamps. 

I found the associated log file (slightly different path, $ORACLE_HOME\cfgtoollogs\opatch) and added a screenshot to the original post.

Lastly, this is on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

Comment: I'm not sure about Winodows server but thats opatch logfile not datapatch e.g on my Oel 7 this is the location of  logfile generated by datapatch is`/u01/app/oracle/12.2/db_1/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_3096_2019_11_05_12_06_52/sqlpatch_invocation.log`. Start elevated command prompt ,set correct environment  and run `datapatch -verbose` byw is it RAC and Prod server.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it was for opatch too, but it was still generated when I ran 'datapatch -verbose' as administrator and I don't see any datapatch specific files or folders. I'll do some more digging and see if I can find anything else. And no, this is not a RAC environment and it is not Prod, just a Test server.

Comment: Try to startup database in upgrade mode `1 ) shutdown immediate 2)startup upgrade 3) datapatch -verbose`

Comment: Looking at examples of other peoples error logs/invocation files, I think that might be from newer versions of Oracle (12.1.0.2?) or maybe datapatch errored out before it produced it? Unfortunately I'm not seeing much on the server.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. I tried shutting down, starting in upgrade mode, and rerunning datapatch but it produces the exact same output as before.

Comment: No I tested on 12cR1 here is the [log files](https://pastebin.com/00VhFR8g) on linux server

Comment: Is it CDB database?.Create pfile from spfile. Add this line to pfile `_oracle_script=true` start database in upgrade mode and run datapatch.

Comment: Sorry for the delay (going to be out of town again for a few days too). No, it's not a container db. I created a pfile from a spfile, added that line, and started up the db with the new pfile but unfortunately still got the same output.

Comment: Also just wanted to ask, how big of a deal is it to not run datapatch? I don't know much about what this part of the patching process is actually doing. I know part of it is updating the system tables showing what patches have been applied, and that it updates other "sql stuff" but I'm not sure how vital it is.

Comment: The datapatch is critical; part of the other things it might be doing, depending on the patch content, is inserting data into new or existing system tables needed for the patch.  So to put it another way, running OPatch and not running datapatch could be worse than not running OPatch at all.